# Validation is not working in Metronic UI. Why?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, metronic

Validation is not working properly. Its always shows This field is required. Even if I don't touch this field. Why?

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Description<span class="required"> * </span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="name-error">
      <span id="name-error" class="help-block help-block-error">This field is required.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, Metronic is included in Aspnet Zero. Are you using Aspnet Zero?

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu yes using aspnet zero

Comment: why not go the angular way and use forms for valdiation

Comment: What do you mean by "don't touch this field"?

Comment: @JeffMattson means user has not done anything with this field.

Comment: @RahulSingh how to do that?

Comment: validation using forms in Angular [reactive forms](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) and [teamplate driven forms](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template)

Comment: You have a span with "*This field is required*", how are you hiding it ? And  I am not able to reproduce the issue, can you create an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the `name="name"` to the label.

Also add `for="name"` to the label.

Comment: It also looks like you have `class="required"` on the label.  I may mis-understand your question but doesn't that make the field required? Of course only if you associate the label with the input field by adding the `for="name"` above.  If you don't want it to be a required field remove the `class="required"`.

Answer (score 0):

Label's "for" attribute is bound to HTML element by element_id.

Remove the `class="required"` on the label and add required attribute to the input field if is needed.

```
<label for="element_id">
<input type="text" id="element_id" required>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```